# Find an invertible non-diagonal $3 \times 3$ matrix $D$ such that $D^3 = D$.

Tags: matrices, idempotents

> Find an invertible non-diagonal $3 \times 3$ matrix $D$ such that $D^3 = D$.

I have forgotten how to solve this kind of question, can somebody give me some hint or idea how to start?

Comment: The title is not supposed to replace the first line of your question. The only possible candidate is $D_3$ and what is $D_3$ anyway?

Comment: Did you mean $D^3=d$?

Comment: I mean the cube of D equals D, D is just a symbol.

Comment: Have you tried taking a diagonal matrix with this property and conjugating it by something to make it non-diagonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D^3-D=0$, the minimal polynomial $\mu_D(x)$ divides $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)$, but $D$ is invertible hence $\mu_D(x)$ divides $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$. Since the matrix $D$ is not diagonal, $D\ne\pm I$ hence $\mu_D(x)\ne x\pm1$, hence $\mu_D(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$. No factor of $\mu_D(x)$ has degree greater than $1$ hence $D$ is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, that is:

> The solutions $D$ are the non-diagonal matrices similar to the diagonal matrix with diagonal $(1,1,-1)$ or to the diagonal matrix with diagonal $(1,-1,-1)$.

Example: $D=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\2&1&2\\-2&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $D^3 = D$ is invariant under similarity, i.e. if $D$ is a solution then so is $SDS^{-1}$ for any nonsingular $S$.  Find a diagonal matrix that satisfies the equation (and is not a multiple of the identity) and take some 
random $S$.

Answer (score 1):

An idempotent matrix ($A^2=A$) matrix also has $A^n=A$, so therefore this question reduces to the following question:

[Constructing idempotent matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/constructing-idempotent-matrices)

Comment: The matrix $A=-I$ solves $A^3=A$ but is not idempotent. (And I love the upvote.)

Comment: @Did - my mistake, that's not what I meant to write. Fixed.

Comment: But now you proved that every idempotent is solution, not that every solution is idempotent.

Comment: @Did, yes: The OP only needed a single instance.

Comment: Oh, I see. $ $ $ $