# What is the square matrix $A$ equal to if $A=A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is: 
If A is a square matrix such that $A^2=A$ then $A^n =A$ for all natural numbers $n$  greater than one. What is $A$ if $A \ne 0$ and $A \ne I$.

I figured out an answer but I can't tell if that's the only answer. Let's say that $a_{kk}$ is a value in $A$. Every value in $A$ is $0$ except for $a_{kk}$ and $a_{00}$, they're $1$. I haven't gotten this answer mathematically.

I've tried a few approaches but ended up with the identity matrix.

Comment: Hint: If $A^2=A$, then what follows about the eigenvalues?

Comment: It would be very good if you could prove that is necessary (sufficiency should be trivial).

Comment: I have no idea, haven't learned about eigenvalues yet.  @celtschk

Comment: This question (find idempotent matrices) is treated in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix)

Comment: There are maaany such matrices and there is no simple way of describing their entries (in particular, their entries can be different from 0 and 1)

Comment: @E.Bob: Then maybe first look at a general diagonal matrix. What does $A^2=A$ imply for those?

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42283)

Answer (score 3):

Such a matrix is called *idempotent*. [Here are some examples and properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix).

Comment: Also relevant is the notion of a projection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Thorough remark

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one more example, besides $A=0$ and $A=I$ may be insightful: take the block matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \cr
0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Of course, $A=A^2$, but $A\neq 0,I$. The (square) blocks can be of any size, so we obtain several examples. Up to similarity, these are the only ones, too. See "canonical forms" in the wikipedia article.

Comment: This is not very different from the example the OP has found by him/her self.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, indeed. But since it said" I haven't gotten this answer mathematically", I wanted to give a clarification. In addition I pointed out that all projection matrices are similar to these.

Comment: You are right, because an idempotent matrix is diagonalizable, and that its eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$.