# Curious Case of Idempotent Matrices - Seeking a Generalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

Here's what I initially started with:

> > Find a 2x2 non zero matrix $A$, satisfying $A^2=A$, and $A\neq I$.

I understand that this is fairly easy, **but please keep reading for something interesting coming up** -

Let's bash it. Assume a matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix}a&b \\c&d\end{bmatrix}$. Putting $A^2 = A$ gives me the following system to solve:

- $bc = a(1-a)$
- $bc = d(1-d)$
- $b(a+d)=b$
- $c(a+d)=c$

Some conclusions:

1. If $a+d = 1$, then $bc = ad$. That is, if we assume a certain value
   for a, we have d, and choosing a value for b, gets us c (or the
   other way round). So, knowing one of the tuples $(a,b), (a,c),
   (d,b),$ or $(d,c)$ determines the matrix $A$. On the other hand, if we choose $b$ and $c$ to begin with, we know $a$ and $d$ from the obvious quadratic equations that follow. Knowing the tuple $(b,c)$ also determines the matrix.
2. If $a+d\neq 1$, then $(b,c)$ must be (0,0) for the last two
   equations to hold. Next, we're left with $a^2=a$ and $d^2=d$, which
   means $(a,d)$ is $(1,1)$ (we reject $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ since that'd
   mean $a+d=1$, and also $(0,0)$ since it'd result in a null matrix).
   This means that, if $a+d\neq1$, then $a+d=2$ with $a=d=1$, and
   $(b,c)=(0,0)$.
   *We seem to have no power here (can't choose variables the way we did in the previous case), as $a+d\neq1$ alone determines the entire
   matrix.* **Anyway, we shall ignore this for now, since we demand $A\neq I$**

In conclusion, **knowing one of the rows or columns determines the entire matrix.** (the matrix not being null, or identity). Also, **knowing the diagonal other than the main diagonal determines the entire matrix.**

*The observation here, is that in a $2$x$2$ matrix, which has $4$ entries, knowing any pair of entries other than the one along the main diagonal helps us determine other entries.*

**Why is it so? Could we have said this without going through such cumbersome algebraic weightlifting?**

**Does this generalise for $n$x$n$ idempotent matrices?** That is, can we deduce something along the lines of:

- Knowing any row or column determines the matrix OR
- Knowing a certain minimum number of rows of columns (>1) determines the matrix OR
- Knowing the diagonal other than the main diagonal determines the matrix OR

*really anything along those lines.* My gut came up with the above possibilities, if this apparently interesting pattern is to hold for matrices of higher order. I really feel there's something worth paying attention to, going on here.

I'd love it if y'all could share your thoughts on this, and help me identify a possible pattern. It'd be great to generalize this idea to higher order idempotent matrices, perhaps even others, if there's nothing special about $A^2=A$ here. I think this is a really important question, since it really boils down to, **knowing a constraint in the form of a matrix, how many entries do I need to know, to determine the rest of the matrix?** (*uniquely determine*, if that pleases you)

Hoping to find something amazing, wish y'all a great day!

Comment: Related question: [Constructing idempotent matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/constructing-idempotent-matrices)

Comment: The phenomenon you describe only happen for $n=2$. It justs says that for $n=2$, a non scalar matrix (that is $\neq c I, c\in \mathbb{R}$) has rank $1$. It has nothing to do with begin idempotent.

Comment: Wait. (a,b,c,d) = (1,2,1,3). This is non-scalar, but has rank 2. Do you mean to say that the matrix is not row-equivalent to a scalar matrix, and has rank 1 hence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a projector (eventually non-orthogonal). The projectors are classified by their trace. Assume that $rank(A)=trace(A)=r\in (0,n)$.

$A$ is associated to a (unique) decomposition $\mathbb{R}^n=E\oplus F$ where $dim(E)=r,dim(F)=n-r$. The couple $(E,F)$ -and then $A$- depends on $r(n-r)+(n-r)r=2r(n-r)$ algebraically independent parameters.

Finally, if you choose skillfully $2r(n-r)$ entries of $A$, then there are only a finite number of possible values for the projector $A$.

In particular, if $r=1$ or $r=n-1$ (projection on a line or on  a hyperplane), then it suffices to fix $2n-2$ entries of $A$ (but not just any).

Comment: Now what is a projector?

Comment: a projector is a projection operator ($A^2=A$). cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Answer (score 2):

> *The observation here, is that in a $2$x$2$ matrix, which has $4$ entries, knowing any pair of entries other than the one along the main diagonal helps us determine other entries.*

This is not true. E.g. we have
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&x\\ 0&0}=\pmatrix{1&x\\ 0&0}^2
$$
for every $x$. Here you are given the first column and the second row of $A$, but you cannot determine $x$ without further information.

Comment: Oh right, I missed the part where a+d = 1 and bc = 0. Cool! Well, now, is there any generalization to see?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ any basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or the field of your choice). Fix $k$ with $1\le k<n$ (to avoid trivial cases) and define the linear map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by decreeing that
$$
f(v_i)=\begin{cases}
v_i & 1\le i\le k \\[1ex]
0   & k<i\le n
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$
Then clearly $f(f(v_i))=f(v_i)$ for $1\le i\le n$, so the map $f$ is idempotent, that is, $f^2=f$. Its matrix $A$ with respect to the standard basis will be idempotent as well.

Conversely, let $A$ be an idempotent matrix (not the zero matrix or the identity matrix); note that $A(I-A)=0$, so the matrix is not invertible. Let $X=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n:Av=v\}$ and $Y=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n:Av=0\}$.

Clearly, $X\cap Y=\{0\}$. Moreover if $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$
v=Av+(v-Av)
$$
Note that $A(Av)=A^2v=Av$, so $x=Av\in X$; also $A(v-Av)=Av-A^2v=Av-Av=0$, so $y=v-Av\in Y$. Therefore, from $v=x+y$, $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, we conclude that $\mathbb{R}^n=X+Y$.

By independence of the two subspace we get that $n=\dim X+\dim Y$. If you fix a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ of $X$ and a basis $\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ of $Y$, then $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis satisfying the same conditions as in $(1)$.

---

In the case $n=2$, the matrix $A$ has rank $1$, so a nonzero column (or row) “determines” the other column, in the sense that the other one must be a scalar multiple.

For instance, if the first column is nonzero, we need
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & ra \\
c & rc
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the conditions $A^2=A$ reads, when $a\ne0$ and $c\ne0$,
$$
r=\frac{1-a}{c}
$$
If $a=0$, then $c\ne0$ and the form of the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
If $c=0$, then $a\ne0$, but this implies $a=1$, and the form of the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$